# How to read env.properties data in application.yml

Tags: spring-boot, cloud

Application.yml

```yaml
spring:
      config:
       #enable this while running spring config server
        import: optional:configserver:http://localhost:8888/pat-tbx-dlr-product-config
```

I need to configure this url in each `application-env.properties` file. like for `application-local.properties` it shall be like:

```
 http://localhost:8888/pat-tbx-dlr-product-config
```

and for `application-prod.properties` it shall shall be like:

```
http://stage/pat-tbx-dlr-product-config
```

and i will dynamically access all these properties from `application.yml.` Help !!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
spring:
  config:
    import: 
      optional:
        configserver: ${config.server.url}
```

And in `env.properties` you will have next one param : `config.server.url` for every stage.

Also for your information `env properties` override the value from `.yml` properties